# how to add parameter of type Class <? extends broadcastreceiver>

Tags: java, android, generics

I have to use a method with this signature

```
BCR(String id, Class<? extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver> 
receiverClass))
```

I created a class extends a BroadcastReceiver as follows

```
public class BCRGeoReference extends BroadcastReceiver {

public BCRGeoReference(Context ctx) {

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
}
```

but I when i add BCRGeoReference to the method i receive an error saying:

```
required java.lang.class<? extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver>
```

please let me know how to add that parameter to the method BCR() posted above

Comment: Are you asking how to call that method with your `BCRGeoReference` class? `BCR("id", BCRGeoReference.class);`.

Comment: how are you calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

Your signature is wrong. You expect a class object with the generic type of `? extends BroadCastReceiver`, but that is not the case. You want to pass an instance of `BroadCastReceiver`.

Change your signature to this

```
<T extends BroadcastReceiver> void BCR(String id, T receiverClass)
```

If you meant to use it as a class object then you have to pass a class. Something like

```
public class TestJava {
    void BCR(String id, Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver> receiverClass){

    }

    public class AnyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestJava test = new TestJava();
        test.BCR("s", AnyReceiver.class);
    }
}
```